# Lineer operators continuty problem in normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

X normed space $T,S:X \to X$ are two operator.If $$ST-TS=I$$ then T or S is not continous prove that

> > I is unit operator $Iv=v $,$\forall v \in X$ ,
> > $T.S=ToS$

Comment: What have you tried in this problem?

Comment: I tried TS=ST when T=k.I k is a scalar but I cant  solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that both $T$ and $S$ are bounded. We need to prove that their commutator cannot be the identity operator.

We will use the following facts:

- For a natural number $n$, $[A,B^n]=nB^{n-1}[A,B]$
- The operator norm is subadditive: $\lVert A + B \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert + \lVert B \lVert$
- The operator norm is submultiplicative: $\lVert AB \rVert \leqslant \lVert A \rVert\lVert B \lVert$

Let's assume that $[S,T]=I$. Then we must have that
$$[S, T^n]=nT^{n-1}[S,T]=nT^{n-1}$$
But:
\begin{align}
\lVert [S, T^n] \rVert
&= \lVert ST^n-T^nS\rVert \\
&\leqslant \lVert ST^n \rVert + \lVert T^n S \rVert \\
&= \lVert S T T^{n-1}\rVert + \lVert T^{n-1} T S \rVert \\
&\leqslant 2\lVert S \rVert \lVert T \rVert \lVert T^{n-1}\rVert
\end{align}
Taking the norm of the commutation relation would imply that
$$\lVert [S, T^n] \rVert = n \lVert T^{n-1}\rVert$$
So we must have:
$$n\lVert T^{n-1} \rVert \leqslant 2\lVert S \rVert \lVert T \rVert \lVert T^{n-1}\rVert$$
Which is absurd!

Note: This works only if $\lVert T^{n-1} \rVert \neq 0$ for all $n$. But what can we do if it does not hold?

Connection to physics: This proves that the momentum and position operators cannot be bounded at the same time, as they need to satisfy the canonical commutation relation $[x, p]=i\hbar$.